# Adding a new input text box in ckeditor image properties window

Tags: textbox, ckeditor

I want to add a new input text box("image Caption") to "Image Properties" dialog window in CKEditor that gives my user to enter the "image caption" along with existed "URL" and "Alt Text".Is there any way i can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able successfully add the input text box by using the following guides in the ckeditor([www.ckeditor.com](http://www.ckeditor.com)) website itself.Very Useful.

Guide: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Editing_Dialog_Windows

API: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dialog.html

Sample: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/7491/_samples/api_dialog.html